# In snowflake how do you do Minus all?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake how do you do Minus all? I do not see an option in the documentation

Comment: Consider adding tags and elaborate your question to explain what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it directly, but you can try to order your similar records, so the minus only affects one of them, sth like:

```
SELECT job, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY job ORDER BY 1) rn
FROM emp
WHERE deptno=20
MINUS
SELECT job, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY job ORDER BY 1) rn
FROM emp
WHERE deptno=30;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, since your question is a bit vague, but this is the documentation link to the Snowflake MINUS operation:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#minus-except

Comment: Thanks for your response. Minus all differs from usual Minus by not discarding the duplicates. I have not seen any Minus All option in Snowflake, so not sure how that situation is being handled through any keyword directly. I hope that clarifies a bit.